# Independence of ordered statistics part 2

Tags: independence, joint-distribution, order-statistics

In relation to my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208658/independence-and-order-statistics), I have a second problem. How to show that $U_1+U_2$ is independent of $Y_3$?

I can find out the *pdf* of $U_1+U_2$, as well as of $Y_3$, however please help me find their joint distribution. (I was hoping to show that the joint pdf was the product of the marginals; if there is any other way, feel free to suggest)

Comment: @whuber : Can you help me with this?